# How to change background image on button hover in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to change background image of button on mousehover event.
I am using following code:

```
 $("#btnCBI").hover(function () {
     $(this).css({ "background-image": "/Tulips.jpg" });
 });
```

Comment: And what is the question ?

Comment: How do I change background of button?

Comment: You can simply [`use css`](http://jsbin.com/ibapix/1/edit) to achieve this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use `url('path')` with css. You need handler in and handler out to see the effect of [**hover()**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$("#btnCBI").hover(function () {
      $(this).css({ "background-image": "url('/Tulips.jpg')" });
   },
   function () {
      $(this).css({ "background-image": "url('/otherImage.jpg')" });
   }
);
```

You can use [**mouseenter()**](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) if you do not want to change it back when mouse gets out of your button.

```
$("#btnCBI").mouseenter(function () {
   $(this).css({ "background-image": "url('/Tulips.jpg')" });
});
```

Comment: Thanks adeneo, so nice of you.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is using css.

```
<button id="css">CSS</button>
```

CSS

```
​#btnCBI:hover{
    background-image: url(/Tulips.jpg);
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way

define two classes

```
<style>
    .in{
    //your hover image
    }

    .out{
    //your normal image

    }
    </style>
$("#btnCBI").mouseover(function () {
$(this).removeClass('out').addClass('in')
});

$("#btnCBI").mouseout(function () {
$(this).removeClass('in').addClass('out')
});
```